# jelastic security firewall or software/patches for the DDos

Tags: security, nginx, jelastic

The cloud environment I am using is utilizing Nginx. Of course, the Nginx should be configured well secured as the only component that I can control in my environment as the http request(s) receiver. I also observed that fail2ban is also installed on the Nginx component.

My question is that does Jelastic provide any Firewall or othr security softwares/patches for the attacks, such as DDos or Dos attack?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jelastic prevents DDos attacks on platform's level by allowing a certain amount of requests from one IP per certain period of time. Also, in an upcoming Jelastic update  there will be the possibility to manage your firewall by custom settings. To perform it, you should contact your hoster's support team and specify your request.

Regards, 
Jelastic Support